# How to disable images using Python Selenium & Chrome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I have this script writtent to direct me to a webpage. It worked well and removed images but when I add the script to add a proxy, it doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

```
options = Options()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
chromedriver = dir_path + "/chromedriver"
os.environ["webriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
PROXY = "144.76.176.72:8080" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

For the images

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

When I add this, it doesn't work or opens a seperate window that does remove images but it doesn't go to link in script. How can I fix this?